# Accessing data from local storage by content scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to access local storage from content scripts but even though the message passing is working, the output isn't as expected.

CONTENT SCRIPT

```
var varproxy = localStorage.getItem('proxy');  //gets data from options page saved to local storage

var proxy = "proxystring";          

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message:"hey"},
function(response) {

  proxy = response.proxy; 
  console.log(response.proxy);

}
);

console.log(proxy);
```

BACKGROUND PAGE (For message passing)

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
  {
  if (request.message == "hey") 
  {
    sendResponse({proxy: varproxy});
    console.log('response sent');
  } 
  else 
  {sendResponse({});}
  });
```

The console logs the proxy as the value of varproxy and also "response sent" but the

```
console.log(proxy);
```

logs the proxy as "proxystring"

Why isn't the value of proxy getting changed? How do I change it as required?

Answer (score 1):

Message sending -- among lots of chrome API function -- is an **asynchronous** function. The interpreter won't wait for the response, but jumps to the next line. So it can easily happen that log(proxy) will be evaluated first, since communicating with the background page takes some time. As soon as the response is received, the value of proxy changes.

Comment: So if I use something like 
setTimeout(function(){console.log(proxy)},2000);           will I get the expected output?

Comment: I was thinking to suggest you that to test, but finally I deleted it. :) Yes, try it!

Comment: I did try it but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Was the response callback function in contentscript called? Test it with unique logging. Did not you get an error in the background page? I run your code and I got an error, since you didn't define varproxy in the background page. Note: contentscript and background have two different consoles and you can check it differently.

Comment: Okay I tried it again and by using setTimeout() I'm not getting the same result, I'm getting null, which is the same same value that gets logged as response.proxy when logged from inside the response function

Comment: So I guess the background page isn't responding with the correct value, even after I tried replacing variable varproxy with a string

Comment: Did you check the console of the Background page? What can you see there? Can you see the 'response sent' without error? The varproxy is undefined in the background page. You defined it in the contentscript, which is a different page.

Answer (score 1):

Might I recommend you try out another implementation? What about Chrome Storage?

Then you don't need any message passing at all, because you can access chrome storage within content scripts.

Example, this is something I do in my extensions' content script to grab several values from chrome storage:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({HFF_toolbar: 'yes',HFF_logging: 'yes',HFF_timer: '1 Minute'},
function (obj) {
  toolbar_option = obj.HFF_toolbar;
  logging_option = obj.HFF_logging;
  timer_option = obj.HFF_timer;
  /* the rest of my content script, using those options */
```

I personally found this approach much easier, for my purposes anyway, than message passing implementations.